# How can I create an async event emitter in Rust?

Tags: rust, websocket

I'm trying to work on a Discord API. I thought this would be a great method to learn Rust. Unlike the previous languages that I've learnt so far, Rust is a bit different.
The error that I'm getting is:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. This happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block the current thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.
```

My code:
client.rs

```
pub struct Client {
   pub listeners: Mutex<HashMap<String, Vec<Box<dyn Fn(&str) + Send + Sync>>>>,

}
impl Client {
    pub async fn on<F>(&self, event: &str, listener: F)
    where
        F: Fn(&str) + 'static + Send + Sync,
    {
        let mut listeners = self.listeners.lock().await;
        listeners
            .entry(event.to_string())
            .or_insert_with(Vec::new)
            .push(Box::new(listener));
    }

    pub async fn emit(&self, event: &str, data: &str) {
        if let Some(listeners) = self.listeners.lock().await.get(event) {
            for listener in listeners {
                listener(data);
            }
        }
    }
    pub async fn socket(&mut self) {
        env::set_var("RUST_BACKTRACE", "full");
        /* some looping to run websocket */
            match t {
                "READY" => {self.emit("READY", "Bot is ready")},
                 _ => {}
            }
        }
}
```

main.rs

```
async fn main() {
    let mut bot: Client = Client::new("");
    bot.socket();
    bot.on("READY", |data| println!("event: {}", data));
}
```

Comment: `main()` can't be async, you're missing some imports, and `t` in `socket()` and `Client::new()` are not defined. Please create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You can potentially use Tokio to have `main` be async.

Comment: @Victor I know, but this is not presented in the example.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that the error is in `/* some looping to run websocket */`, because I don't see anything in your example that can fire it.

Comment: I avoided posting rest of the code because without adding event emitters that code is running. The problems lies when I try to add event emitters and run the code then I get errors. Otherwise the code is running fine, @ChayimFriedman. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Did you try to add event listeners without this code? Does it still panic? If not, the problem lies in their combination and you should show us both.

Comment: It did not. @ChayimFriedman

Comment: Should I create a git repo so that you both can see?

Comment: No, you should post all code here. You can also create a repo, but all code needs to be in the question.

Comment: ```pub struct Client {
    pub TOKEN: String,
    pub write: Option<SplitSink<WsStream, Message>>,
    pub API: Option<reqwest::Client>,
   pub listeners: Mutex<HashMap<String, Vec<Box<dyn Fn(&str) + Send + Sync>>>>,

}

impl Client {
    pub fn new(TOKEN: &str) -> Self {
        Self { TOKEN: String::from(TOKEN), write: None, API: Some(reqwest::Client::new()), listeners: Mutex::new(HashMap::new()) } 
    }``` I tried to post all of the code here but can't post all of it here. I won't waste more of your time but I'm sure that my code is not working on this section.

Comment: Because when I commented `self.emit(..)`, the code didn't worked and I think that is where I'm wrong

Comment: @GaurishTrivedi Please don't post multi-line code in a comment. [Edit] your question instead.

Comment: And as other said, please provide a [MRE]. That is complete, has a `main()`, all required `use` statements, and that produces your exact error message when executed.